# How to set the size of spinner

Tags: android

I want to know how to set the size of spinner.When i added large values to spinner list,the spinner expands and as result it pushes the labelField to the further left.

I want to know the how to set the spinner size to be a constant one

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you presently have the `Spinner` set with `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. That will expand as the values expand. If that is not what you want, do something else. `RelativeLayout` is particularly useful here, as you can anchor both the left and right sides of the `Spinners` to things they should not expand past (e.g., left to another widget, right to the right edge of the screen).

Comment: Hello Sir,I cannot getwhat you are saying,Can u explain in detail Sir

Comment: I believe this answer is referring to the configuration for the spinner in a layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone come to this page again... One may refer to here:

[How to change spinner text size and text color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color)