# How to change spinner text size and text color?

Tags: android, spinner

In my Android application, I am using spinner, and I have loaded data from the SQLite database into the spinner, and it's working properly. Here is the code for that.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
cursor.moveToFirst();

list.add("All Lists");

if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        keyList[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEYWORD));
        list.add(keyList[i]);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
Database.close();
cursor.close();
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Now I want to change the text color and text size of spinner data. I have used following XML lines to my spinner tag on my XML file, but it is not working.

```
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textSize="11dp"
```

How can I change the text color and text size of my spinner?

Comment: check the following sites [StackoverFlow][1] [stackoverflow ][2] [stackoverflow][3]
I think this is duplicate question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880413/text-color-of-a-closed-spinner
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989817/set-the-textsize-to-a-text-in-spinner-in-android-programatically
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836254/android-change-text-color-of-items-in-spinner

Comment: try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159113/android-where-is-the-spinner-widgets-text-color-attribute-hiding

Comment: For textSize the correct is to use SP... android:textSize="11sp"

Answer (score 895, accepted):

Make a custom XML file for your spinner item.

**spinner_item.xml:**

Give your customized color and size to text in this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"  
    android:textColor="#FF0000"         
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```

Now use this file to show your spinner items like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,list);
```

You don't need to set the drop down resource. It will take `spinner_item.xml` only to show your items in spinner.

Comment: @Hiral text will be white just for current selected item.

Comment: @vilpe89 could you modify your above code to show what you mean by this?  where does this android:id go?  certainly not in the spinner tag, because it has it's own id.  but it doesn't make sense to add it in the textview tag you have created above.  how do i reference that i want to use this tag directly from the XML?  also, when creating the XML from Eclipse, I don't see any option to create an XML file containing only a TextView, how does that work???

Comment: Well I have read my comment many times and not sure what I have been thinking by that time :)

Comment: This changed the color of the selected item, but when I open the spinner, the content is still default... on my Nexus 7 at least

Comment: @Hiral, can we use selector as background of `Spinner`?

Comment: Just a little note. Textsize should be using **sp** instead of **dp/dip**

Comment: In which folder should I put custom TextView- in drawable, Layout, Values, etc?

Comment: Hi, as @GyRo asked, the .xml file must be located inside your "layout" folder.

Comment: @Hiral How can you change typeface in that TextView from layout??

Comment: Hi, i used this solution but the textcolor is not changing. Do i have to do something else?

Comment: can't this be done by using style only? I am surprised how small stuff is so difficult to style in android.. this is frustrating.. I wished they had a styling system like css

Comment: If you want to set the dropdown textview too, call `setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.setting_value_spinner_value);`

Comment: use id: android:id="@android:id/text1"

Comment: but what about ARROW's color?

Comment: i think spinner should have this features! its look like weakness

Comment: I think the method ArrayAdapter.createFromResource should be used and the strings put in array in the strings.xml

Comment: @yeahman it can be done through styling as well. You need to define it in the `styles.xml` and then in the layout file in the spinner, you can write `android:theme="@style/Spinner"`. Check out the answers below.

Comment: Also, we can get the entries from array like: 
`mySpinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_spinner,
            resources.getStringArray(R.array.array_options)
        )`

Answer (score 212):

Simple and crisp...:

```
private OnItemSelectedListener OnCatSpinnerCL = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

       ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
       ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(5);

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
};
```

Comment: This is the best solution for me, because I needed to change the color of the text in the spinner, but not in the appearing list. Thank you.

Comment: For me, the item color blinks, going from original color to the color I choosed

Comment: @FelipeConde Did you ever find an answer? I have the same question. My question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908564/setting-spinner-text-color-programmatically-lags-is-slow-is-wrong-color-for-sp

Comment: @FelipieConde For you ,it takes the ascent color at first , then you change into other color manually , So it look so tired.

At First It Takes 
<item name="colorAccent">@color/color_primary</item>

Then you manually changed by programmatic,
So you feel the blink

Comment: The above kept crashing for me so I changed it to 
TextView tv = (TextView) view; 
tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

Comment: this worked for me but my problem is when i return from a fragment app crashes as it gets a null pointer on the above code

Comment: To avoid null pointer, add a check like

if (((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)) != null) {
                    ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                }

Comment: The app also crashes due to NPE after screen rotation :/

Answer (score 160):

If all the spinners may have the same text color for their TextView items, another approach is to use a custom style for spinner dropdown items:

In `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="mySpinnerItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_spinner_text_color</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And define your custom color in res/values/colors.xml:

```
<color name="my_spinner_text_color">#808080</color>
```

Comment: And how to apply this solution to Appcompt theme? I dtried it by overriding the parent theme "@style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner" and it didn't work out

Comment: I would add also add:
<item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>

This ensures that the collapsed text has the same color - in case this is the desired behavior.

Comment: does not works for me neither, the style is completely ignored

Comment: @Whypee please edit your answer according to the suggestions of infinite-loop it worked for me perfectly

Comment: For AppCompat theme just remove `android:` like this `<item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>`

Comment: these attributes only work when using  @android:layout/simple_spinner_item as the item layout https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206244#c2

Comment: To be clear, you have to specify the style as a theme, or it won't work:
`<Spinner android:theme="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle" ... />`

Comment: @netimen I used the simple_spinner_item instead of simple_list_item1, but still not working

Answer (score 83):

Here is a link that can help you to **change the color of the Spinner**:

[Click here](http://www.broculos.net/2013/09/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-color.html#.VdM8Opf4Xts)

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:entries="@array/planets"/>
```

You need to create your own layout file with a custom definition for the spinner item **spinner_item.xml**:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ff0000" />
```

If you want to customize the dropdown list items, you will need to create a new layout file. **spinner_dropdown_item.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#aa66cc"/>
```

And finally another change in the declaration of the spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
R.array.planets_array, R.layout.spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

That's it.

Comment: This was an automated response that came from reviewing posts by new users. Glad to see that you edited the answer! :)

Comment: It seems, that `android:textSize="20sp"`in the first code snippet is useless: the textsize of the control is defined in the `spinner_item.xml`

Answer (score 32):

If you work with android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner here is the simplest tested solution using styles:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spefcialFx"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:theme="@style/Spinner"
                    android:entries="@array/special_fx_arrays"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"></android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>
```

And the style:

```
<style name="Spinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>
```

The only downside is the android:backgroundTint sets color for both the dropdown arrow and the dropdown background.

Comment: you use `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"` but you have only `style name="Spinner"`...

Comment: `paddingStart` requires API 17, `backgroundTint` requires API 21.

Answer (score 21):

To prevent lagging, you need to not only set the text properties in the `onItemSelected` listener, but also in the Activity's `onCreate` method (but it's a little tricky).

Specifically, you need to put this in `onCreate` after setting the adapter:

```
spinner.setSelection(0, true);
View v = spinner.getSelectedView();
((TextView)v).setTextColor(backgroundColor);
```

And then put this in `onItemSelected`:

```
((TextView) view).setTextColor(backgroundColor);
```

Here is a full example:

```
@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{  
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner); 

    //Set the choices on the spinner by setting the adapter.  
    spinner.setAdapter(new SpinnerAdapter(toolbar.getContext(), new String[]{"Overview", "Story", "Specifications", "Poll", "Video"}, accentColor, backgroundColor));

    //Set the text color of the Spinner's selected view (not a drop down list view) 
    spinner.setSelection(0, true);
    View v = spinner.getSelectedView();
    ((TextView)v).setTextColor(backgroundColor);

    //Set the listener for when each option is clicked.  
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {  

        @Override  
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {  
           //Change the selected item's text color  
           ((TextView) view).setTextColor(backgroundColor);
        }  

        @Override  
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {  
        }  
    });  

}
```

For more details, see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908564/setting-spinner-text-color-programmatically-lags-is-slow-is-wrong-color-for-sp).

Answer (score 18):

If you want the text color to change in the selected item only, then this can be a possible workaround. It worked for me and should work for you as well.

```
spinner.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                ((TextView) spinner.getSelectedView()).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 10):

we can change style of spinner textview set theme for spinner like this:

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="mySpinnerItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_11ssp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name=...</item>
</style>
```

then

```
<Spinner
                    android:theme="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

if you want to change spinner textview attribute programtically:

**Programatically:**

```
val textView = (view.getChildAt(0) as TextView)
textView.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.dark_mode))
```

Answer (score 9):

For someone who needs only `Style` way for `AppCompat`.

**Result**
[image]
[image]

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    ... 
    <style name="Spinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_grey_700</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**your_spinner_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    ...

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/content_spinner"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/shipping_tracking_carrier_names"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:theme="@style/Spinner" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/content_input"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/material_grey_700"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

**Plus**
And if you want to set `android:entries` programmatically with defined style.
Try this.

```
AppCompatSpinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.content_spinner);
CharSequence[] entries = getResources().getTextArray(R.array.shipping_tracking_carrier_names);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(spinner.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, entries);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

As in the code, using same `Context` with the `Spinner` is most important thing.

```
spinner.getContext()
```

Answer (score 7):

For those who want to change `DrowDownIcon` color
you can use like this

```
spinner.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: can you try `<item name="android:colorControlNormal" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/light_gray</item>`

Comment: put this line in your style `AppTheme`

Comment: This is the code that worked `Drawable spinnerDrawable = spinner.getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable();
    spinnerDrawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_white_1000), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
      spinner.setBackground(spinnerDrawable);
    }else{
      spinner.setBackgroundDrawable(spinnerDrawable);
    }
`

Answer (score 6):

To change the color of spinner text :

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);}
```

Comment: i like this solution too. it's simple and works well.

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to make a small change on the correct answer at the top.
Make a custom XML file for your spinner item inside the layout directory.

**spinner_style.xml**:

Give your customized color and size to text in this file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <TextView  
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textAlignment="inherit"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"         
            android:padding="5dp"
            />
```

Now use this file to show your spinner items inside your java file:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.spinner_style,list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_style);
```

Answer (score 5):

Simplest: Works for me

```
public class NameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    
   ... 
    
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
      TextView spinnerText = (TextView) spinner.getChildAt(0);
      spinnerText.setTextColor(Color.RED);

      ...

   }

   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}

   ...

}
```

Comment: spinner.getChildAt(0) returns null to me :/

Comment: I think this technique is for API 19+.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to re-use/change the android.R.layout resources is just go the definition. In Android Studio, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> on android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item.xml.

It will take you to the resource file. Just copy the resource file and add a new layout in your Package.R.layout folder and change the textColor of textview as you like and then just call it in adapter like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String(Context,R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerlist);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want a simple method, in order to add items to a dropdown, you usually add them to the strings.xml. Here is an example on how to add colour by using the strings.xml file:

SELECT AGE RANGE

```
<string-array name="age_array">

   <item> 0-6 </item>                               //No custom colour

  <item><font fgcolor='#FF4CD964'> 12+ </font></item> //With custom colour

</string-array>
```

Comment: cute trick...  useful and fast for a one off spinner, color needs to be a raw color value string not from xml

Answer (score 5):

Can change the text colour by overriding the getView method as follows:

```
 new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list()){
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    //change the color to which ever you want                    
                    ((CheckedTextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    //change the size to which ever you want                    
                    ((CheckedTextView) view).setTextSize(5);
                    //for using sp values use setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
                    return view;
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than making a custom layout to get a small size and if you want to use Android's internal small size LAYOUT for the spinner, you should use:

"android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item" instead of "android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item".

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> madaptor = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(rootView.getContext(),
                                R.array.String_visitor,
                                android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item);
```

It can reduce the size of spinner's layout. It's just a simple trick.

If you want to reduce the size of a drop down list use this:

```
madaptor.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

just use this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_category = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.spinner_list_item, categories);
adapter_category
    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variation of Ashraf's solution would be to make sure you're taking into account screen sizes.  You'll need to get the spinner in onCreate and set the listener after you set the adapter:

```
//set your adapter with default or custom spinner cell, then://
serverSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerSelector);
serverSpinner.setSelection(defaultServer);
```

Then you can start changing the text size of the view that's showing before the spinner is clicked:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener spinnerSelector = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
        boolean largeTablet = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isLargeTablet);
        if (tabletSize) { ((TextView)parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(16); }
        else if (largeTablet) { ((TextView)parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(18); }
        else { ((TextView)parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(12); }
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
};
```

All you need to do is create layout specific folders like this:

> values-sw360dp
>
> values-sw600dp
>
> values-sw800dp

an then add an xml file named "bool.xml" into each of those folders:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
    <bool name="isLargeTablet">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

First we have to create the simple `xml` resource file for the `textview` like as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"  
    android:textColor="#FF0000"         
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```

and save it. after set on your adapterlist.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method. It is working for me.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) view;
    ((TextView) adapterView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.RED);
    ((TextView) adapterView.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(20);
    Toast.makeText(this, textView.getText()+" Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I think this is a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can have this type of adapter for spinner, totally customized:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> genderAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_text, genderList) {

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ((TextView) v).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16);
            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#676767"));
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(vrFont);
            return v;
        }

        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            ((TextView) v).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16);
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(vrFont);
            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#676767"));

            if (position == 0) {
                ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#979797"));
            }

            return v;
        }
```

while R.layout.spinner_text is:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:maxLines="1"
android:textColor="@color/whiteThree" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String typeroutes[] = {"Select","Direct","Non Stop"};
    Spinner typeroute;

    typeroute = view.findViewById(R.id.typeroute);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, typeroutes) {
            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    // Disable the first item from Spinner
                    // First item will be use for hint
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                ((TextView) v).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16);
                ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                return v;
            }         ---->in this line very important so add this

            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                        ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                if (position == 0) {
                    // Set the hint text color gray
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                } else {
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
                return view;
            }
        };

        arrayAdapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        typeroute.setAdapter(arrayAdapter5);
```

that's all enjoy your coding...

Answer (score 0):

I have done this as following.I have use getDropDownView() and getView() methods.

Use `getDropDownView()` for opened Spinner.

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = convertView;
  if (view == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = vi.inflate(R.layout.context_row_icon, null);
  }
  TextView mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.context_label);
  ImageView flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.context_icon);                

  mTitle.setText(values[position].getLabel(activity));

  if (!((LabelItem) getItem(position)).isEnabled()) {
    mTitle.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.context_item_disabled));
  } else {
    mTitle.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.context_item));
  }
  return view;
}
```

And Use `getView()` for closed Spinner.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = convertView;
  if (view == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = vi.inflate(R.layout.context_row_icon, null);
  }
  TextView mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.context_label);
  ImageView flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.context_icon);

  mTitle.setText(values[position].getLabel(activity));
  mTitle.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.context_item_disabled));

  return view;
}
```

Comment: It is properly tested code and worked in application in appstore

Answer (score -2):

just add new style like this:

```
<style name="mySpinnerItemStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:color">#000</item>
</style>
```

and use it:

```
<Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinnerCategories"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
      android:layout_margin="5dp" />
```