# How to change the Text color of Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

Please help me on changing the text color of the spinner.

Comment: Please go through the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color

Comment: How themes control spinner styling is explained here: http://tekeye.biz/2012/changing-android-spinner-text-size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

**custom_spinner_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/iphone_text" />
```

In Java code

```
Spinner spnCategory= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
```

..

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adptSpnCategory = new ArrayAdapter<String>this,R.layout.custom_spinner_item, alCategoryName);
adptSpnCategory.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spnCategory.setAdapter(adptSpnCategory);
spnCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
 {
 }
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
 {
 }
});
```

Comment: but it increase size of spinner also. In my case I make transparent spinner view and place it nearer view. So if follow above mention it affect spinner dialog and spinner view size as well...any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
    TextView tv = (TextView) spinner.getSelectedView();
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

otherwise change in spinner_xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="20dip"
     android:gravity="left"  
     android:textColor="#FF0000"         
     android:padding="5dip"
/>
```

Comment: be carefull, getSelectedView() should be called AFTER an item is selected.