# How to change spinner button color in Android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm trying to change the spinner button color in Android but I can't get it working. Can anyone help?

```
  <Spinner
       android:id="@+id/spinner1"
       android:layout_width="200dp"
       android:layout_height="35dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
       android:background="@null"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"

       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417755/change-android-spinner-text-color-when-button-pressed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188398/how-to-change-the-spinner-background-design-and-color-for-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a android specialist but does this help you?:
The Spinner button uses a nine-patch image (http://www.aspose.com/java/imaging-component.aspx). You need to make a nine-patch image in all the different resolutions and then set it as the spinner's background.

See:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 4):

you can use this :

```
Drawable spinnerDrawable = mySpinner.getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable();
    spinnerDrawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_m), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) 
{
 mySpinner.setBackground(spinnerDrawable);
} else {
 mySpinner.setBackgroundDrawable(spinnerDrawable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the spinners background color in xml like this:

`android:background="YOUR_HEX_COLOR_CODE"`

You can also set a drawable in the background

`android:background=@drawable/my_spinner`

Answer (score 0):

Here are two extra links:

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html

http://android-holo-colors.com/ (if you want the same shape, just different color (and good for overall themeing)

Comment: still i did not get answer. spinner does not chaning..still it is in bleck color. what i have to do?

Comment: does this link to another stackoverflow question help you?:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188398/how-to-change-the-spinner-background-design-and-color-for-android

Comment: or here a online tutorial: http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-get-holo-spinner-theme-in-android-2-x/

Answer (score 0):

Using XML what worked for me was: `android:backgroundTint="hex_color"`.

If you are using a Spinner with Underlined style (e.g. `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined`), it also changes the line color.