# How to change Spinner text and button color

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner, android-spinner

I am trying to change the color of the text and the button for the Spinner function programatically. how can i change the text and button color of my spinner without changes in the xml??

Following code:

```
Spinner label_Col_5_dataSpinner = new Spinner(this);
label_Col_5_dataSpinner.setId(200+Count);
String[] label_Col_5_data= new String[]{"Vivian","Xiaomi","Chris","Bill","Luyi"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,label_Col_5_data );
label_Col_5_dataSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
label_Col_5_dataSpinner.setPadding(30, 20, 30, 20);
label_Col_5_dataSpinner.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
//label_Col_5_dataSpinner.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

tr.addView(label_Col_5_dataSpinner);
```

Comment: You have to create your own adapter. An example : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6661762/3922326

Answer (score 3):

for change button color you can use this :

```
    Drawable spinnerDrawable = mySpinner.getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable();


    spinnerDrawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_m), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
      {  mySpinner.setBackground(spinnerDrawable); }  
    else
     {  mySpinner.setBackgroundDrawable(spinnerDrawable); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way -

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(OnCatSpinnerCL);
```

and define this as -

```
private OnItemSelectedListener OnCatSpinnerCL = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                long id) {
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(getResources()
                    .getDimension(R.dimen.detail_spinner_text_size));

            // Change the color here as well 
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    };
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

***If you are using xml .... Since its easy and powerful***

---

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- Remove shadow below actionbar -->
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

        <!-- set background for entire application -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/app_background</item>

        <!-- For the resting Spinner style -->
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">
            @style/spinnerItemStyle
        </item> 

        <!-- For each individual Spinner list item once clicked on -->
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
            @style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle
        </item>


    </style>



    <!-- Spinner Custom color -->

     <style name="spinnerItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <!-- <item name="android:padding">10dp</item> -->
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00aeef</item>
    </style>

    <style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
       <!--  <item name="android:padding">20dp</item> -->
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00aeef</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use the :

```
  Button >> on click open dialog
```

OR

```
  AutoCompleteTextView >> as u start typing it will show as dropdown list
```

Answer (score 0):

For text color hopefully this will work:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
TextView tv = (TextView) spinner.getSelectedView();
tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

The best and easiest solution to change the button color:

```
spinner.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.red), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Other solution if you don't want change all Spinners:

```
Drawable spinnerDrawable = spinner.getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable();

spinnerDrawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.red), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    spinner.setBackground(spinnerDrawable);
}else{
    spinner.setBackgroundDrawable(spinnerDrawable);
}
```

For more information check out: [How to change the Text color of Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833714/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-spinner) (for text color)

&

[Change colour of small triangle on spinner in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911287/change-colour-of-small-triangle-on-spinner-in-android) (for button color)

Hope it helps! Good Luck!