# Why spinner size is changed after loading data and text color?

Tags: android, spinner, retrofit, android-spinner, retrofit2

When I load data to the spinner from web service using Retrofit, It increase the height of the spinner and change text color. What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Red marked spinner is the standard size without loading any data.

[image]

Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_monthly_target_ad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.nitolniloygroup.operating.view.activity.MonthlyTargetADActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerZone" />


        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerSubZone" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerBranch" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerFieldOfficer" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerFieldOfficeraaa" />

        <Button
            android:text="Search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
            android:onClick="onClickSearch"
            android:id="@+id/button4" />




    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check out the answer..i added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change spinner size: use `padding` to 0dp

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerSubZone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:padding="0dp"  //add this
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
```

To change text color: overwrite `setOnItemSelectedListener` method in your spinner object

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.RED); //change color
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(10);  //change size
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

or u can use a custom adapter class see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833714/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-spinner)

Answer (score 2):

because you make spinner height warp_content.
to avoid that give spinner a specific height like 80dp

Comment: Thanks. But I cant change the color, gravity and size. Whats the problem? It is not working.

            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:gravity="center"

Comment: @durloveroy you can implement your custom spinner adapter and also specify your spinner items as text view which allows you to specify item gravity and item text color  and text size

Comment: see this tutorial @durloveroy http://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-spinner-examples.html

Answer (score 1):

You can set minimum height of Spinner:

```
android:minHeight="80dp"
```

Comment: Thanks. But I cant change the color, gravity and size. Whats the problem? It is not working.

            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:gravity="center"

Comment: If you want to use desire color then you have to implement your own Spinner Adapter. Then you can change style.