# Is there way to change the size of the text in spinner?

Tags: android

i am trying to change font size in spinner by writing in xml file in layout as follows.But it seems that the text size appears in spinner remains unchanged. Can any body answer me how . I am writing my code here...`<Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner12"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:textSize="15sp" />`

Comment: You need to change text size of spinner items ?

Comment: For that you can use custom view for spinner item

Comment: You could see the answer to [this][1] question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color

Answer (score 2):

You can make a separate xml layout file for each spinner item. and call it from the array adapter. It should work .