# Spinner textSize doesn't change the fontsize in the app

Tags: android, spinner, text-size

I am using the `xml` in my `layout` folder to declare my spinners. For example:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/foo_spinner"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

I load the spinner entries within my code. My problem is that the text size isn't affected. I can put `100sp` there but nothing will happen. Do I have to change it only after I load the spinner content? Do I need to do this after every time I update the content?

Comment: you should customize your spinner, look to this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color

Comment: `android:textSize` isn't an attribute of [Spinner.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to customize the text size `Spinner` item then you will have to use custom layout from `Spinner` item.

Suppose, create an custom `TextView` layout for `Spinner` item named `custom_spinner_item.xml` as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Now, use this layout XML to show your spinner items like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_spinner_item, list);
```

**Another thing,** you should use `dp` or `dip` instead of `sp` for `android:layout_width` attribute and `android:textSize` isn't appropriate for `Spinner` element.

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/foo_spinner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to set the style at the beginning of the code and not to update it every time I update the spinner? I'll be doing that quite often.