# Android : How can i Customize Spinner items?

Tags: android, spinner

This is my Spinner with Package names of Installed apps as ArrayList. It works fine but the text on spinner items appear white and the text is not visible untill focused. I need to set the item color to black, how can i?

```
public class AppList extends Activity
{
    private Spinner spinner;
    private ArrayList results = new ArrayList();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Button);


        PackageManager pm = AppList.this.getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);


        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list)
        {       results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.packageName.toString());
        }

       spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
}}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color

Comment: For that you need to make Custom spinner xml file in which your TextView color will be black and after that you can use that layout file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);
    adaptersetDropDownViewResource(R.layout.your_layout);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Make a layout xml with only textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:textcolor="@android:color/black"/>
```

Comment: Sooo crisp, worked like a charm, thnx but now the problem is height of items are not equal because of text. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: @RashedLone Do you mean the height of dropdown element and spinner?

Comment: @RashedLone Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @RashedLone You can give the padding to the textview to make it big, or increase its size.

Comment: @RashedLone You can make the textview single line by android:singleLine=true

Comment: @RashedLone Why did you changed the correct answer? I already gave the same answer which you marked correct.

Comment: Oh!! by mistake, Sorry. I accepted your answer as correct. Thnx, I'm done. God bless you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54220/discussion-between-rashed-lone-and-berserk).

Answer (score 0):

Extend the adapter, and customize the view in `getView` and `getDropdownView`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your **simple_list_item_1**.xml file

Add this your textview;

```
 android:textColor="#000000"
```

Comment: It's not possible, it's android Layout xml

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adap = new     ArrayAdapter<String>     (this,
android.R.layout.simple_
spinner_item, your_array );
    adap.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.row);
        spinner.setAdapter(adap);
```

Now Customize the text in row.xml