# Android: Populate spinner dynamically then change its font color

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have array that populate its item from JSON using this method

```
JSONObject dataProvinsi = new JSONObject(data.getString("data"));
ArrayList<CharSequence> arrKota = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray jsArrKota = dataProvinsi.getJSONArray("kota");
if(jsArrKota.length() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < jsArrKota.length(); i++) {
        arrKota.add(jsArrKota.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

Then my spinner populate its item from those array. This is my code to populate spinner item

```
ProvinsiAdapter provinsiAdapter = new ProvinsiAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrKota);
spRujukanKota.setAdapter(provinsiAdapter);
```

I created my own adapter class

```
public class ProvinsiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<CharSequence> itemsArrayList;

    public ProvinsiAdapter(Context context,int resource, ArrayList<CharSequence> itemsArrayList) {

        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, itemsArrayList);

        this.context = context;
        this.setDropDownViewResource(resource);
        this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
    }
}
```

My spinner works well, but there is some problem I am facing. My spinner text goes white and I can't change its color into black. My question is, how I can change spinner text color? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using the native layout which id called: "android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item" system will display this layout with its specifications.

So what you have to do?!

you have two choices:

A- to open this layout and look for the id of the textView which is "R.id.text1"
then override **"getView()"** method, which is in your custom adapter, and change text's color using this code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parent, false);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    textView.setTextColor(R.color.your_color);

    return convertView;
}
```

Or: B- you can do your work your way (Custom adapter with custom layout)
and you will override getView same way too.

You can take a look in this link for further clarification :
[how to change spinner text size and text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color)

Comment: Case A: Which class should I override getView method?

Case B: I tried using this method by create adapter like ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,list); but it gives me error **cannot resolve constructor array adapter ... ** this error said it was related to Volley lib that I am using. Does my adapter creation goes right?

Comment: in Case A: just override getView method in your custom adapter as I mentioned, in this case it is your "ProvinsiAdapter"

in Case B: change the ArrayAdapter with BaseAdapter and every thing will go fine. But you have to take care of "itemsArrayList" by your self.

Comment: Really thank you, Mohammad Sayed. It solved by following case B. Creating new style and using it as layout on adapter.

Comment: Welcome @SonicMaster ^_^ it's a pleasure ^_^