# Spinner color style in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-studio

I am making `Spinner` like below image. It's work fine as I want. But I want to change `background` color to `#FFFFFF` and `textColor` to `#000000`. But I got revise output...

[image]

java code:

```
Spinner staticSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.static_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.request_role,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        staticAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        staticSpinner.setAdapter(staticAdapter);
```

xml code :

```
<Spinner
         android:id="@+id/static_spinner"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="45dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
         style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.DropDownItem"     ></Spinner>
```

simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#000000"

  />
```

simple_spinner_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

        <item name="colorPrimary">#0072BA</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#004F80</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#0072BA</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">48dp</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">48dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: make your own custom layout for adapter.

Comment: I make both Textview different file but the problem is same.

Comment: you are calling the android layout not your own custom layout android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

Comment: But I don't want to make extra file for that ???

Comment: look at this-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color

Comment: @sumit singh    your link not work even the spinner is Invisible.

Comment: My code is work  fine But now i want only textcolor="#FFFFFF" to textColor="#000000".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using below code I can solve my problem.

```
  <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/static_spinner2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/apptheme_spinner_background_holo_light"
                android:popupBackground="#ffffff" />
```

**Spinner_item.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

**spinner_dropdown_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

**java code :**

```
Spinner staticSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.static_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter =
                ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.request_role,R.layout.spinner_item);

        staticAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        staticSpinner.setAdapter(staticAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this spinner in your code

```
 <Spinner
    style="@style/edit_style"
    android:id="@+id/spr_city"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_spinner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/min_height"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    />
```

and make this style in style .xml

```
 <style name="edit_style" >
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

and use this code in activity

```
       ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>        (activity,R.layout.spinner_item_selected,city_list);
    adp1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
    s_city.setAdapter(adp1);
```

and create xml spinner_item_selected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textViewSpinnerItem"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="@dimen/common_margin"
style="@style/edit_style"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

and one more xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TextView
android:id="@+id/textViewSpinnerItem"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="@dimen/common_margin"
style="@style/edit_style"
android:textColor="@color/spinner_item_selector"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Comment: Specify java code and last xml in deep I coundn't understand what you say.

Comment: what you want to understand tell me

Answer (score 1):

You can set the spinners background color in xml like this:

```
android:background="YOUR_HEX_COLOR_CODE"
```

and if you use the drop down menu with you spinner you can set its background color like this:

```
android:popupBackground="YOUR_HEX_COLOR_CODE"
```

Comment: I have set android:popupBackground="#FFFFFF" but coundn't set textColor="#000000"

Comment: check this link http://www.broculos.net/2013/09/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-color.html#.Voo7JbZ97IV

Answer (score 0):

change android.R to yourprojcet.R

```
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
```

to

```
letmobility.com.itforte.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item;
```

it is taking android layout instead of your app specific layout.

Comment: means add package name instead of android

Comment: import letmobility.com.itforte.R; instaed of android.R;

Comment: could u give another solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Your call should be like this :

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = 
   ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.request_role,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

      staticAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

instead of :

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.request_role,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    staticAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: Bro you give wrong solution. Read the question properly I want to change the color of text.

Comment: @harshadpansuriya i know what your question is and 'setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); ' will show the color of text as u declared in xml.

Comment: ok but your code can give me output like  stop Unfortunately error