# change spinner text color in java code/android?

Tags: java, android, text, colors, spinner

I have the following spinner xml code:

```
  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.40"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_rectangle"/>
```

and the following java code:

public void setMainCategories(String[] mainCategories) {

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mainCategories);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerMain.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

}

@Override
public void setSubcategories(String[] subCategories) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subCategories);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerSub.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

and I'm not sure how to change the java code for the text to change color.

Do you have any suggestions? 
Would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: do you want to change the color of the text in dropdown or the one which is selected?

Comment: You need to implement a custom adapter

Comment: I need each and every text in the spinner to be in black, the main category a bolder black. Thanks

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12353253/6255373
It's should be what are you searching.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Appearance of Dropdown Items in the Spinner via Styles:

Add a style XML and use the in-built Android attribute:

```
<style name="mystyle">
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/spinner_drop_item_style</item>
</style>
<style name="spinner_drop_item_style">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|start</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/apptheme_list_selector</item>
</style>
```

Depending on your usecase a custom View like @Jhaman proposed might be the easier solution.

EDIT: You have also apply the Style somehow to your view or Application. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) is good in explaining this, but all in all the Style system and the various attributes are not that well described.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom XML file for your spinner item.

**spinner_item.xml:**

Give your customized color and size to text in this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"  
    android:textColor="#FF0000"         
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```

Now use this file to show your spinner items like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,list);
```

Hope it will helps you :)