# Android Spinner Underline color

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-appcompat, underline

I can add underline in spinner using `style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"`. How can I change the color of the underline using style only? I don't want to use any drawable file to change this.

```
 <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
 <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

Using above style, Its only highlight underline when user click on it. Its not changing color of underline on normal state.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

By default the `Spinner` will use the color set via `android:textColorSecondary` or `colorControlNormal` in your `AppTheme`. So either set the appropriate colors there or define a new Theme and apply this one to your Spinner:

#### Example:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ThemeSpinner">
    <!-- Color when pressed -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#ffa000</item>
    <!-- Default color for the dropdown arrow and line -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffc107</item>
</style>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<Spinner
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeSpinner" />
```

***Note:*** *The dropdown arrow will also be tinted - I'm not aware of an option to color the arrow separately*

Comment: This won't work if the Spinner is inside a ScrollView.

Comment: what about the red color for the error? Is there a way to get it?

Comment: @kingston I've never seen a `Spinner` with an error state honestly

Comment: Just try to add a new account in any of the Google app. It will ask you for the date of birth. Enter an invalid date and then press next...

Comment: I asked a question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792721/spinner-with-error-in-android

Comment: Works **PERFECTLY** with this implementation of style: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color

Answer (score 4):

Add this to spinner

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like this question has already been answered. But here is a way to resolve that programatically as well. (Tested on API 19 & Above).

Use `ViewCompat` for this.

```
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(spinner, ColorStateList.valueOf(your_color));
```

Comment: it applies color but in an unexpected way, because it applies it on top of the original color

Comment: This has worked for me when I last tried, but may need some fiddling with your UI, because android Compat libs and components have changed since I last used.