# Spinner with error in Android

Tags: android, spinner

I'm using a Spinner with the new style

```
Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined
```

I can see the underline and the line is shown with the accent color while I'm selecting the option.

The problem is that I could not find a way to show the error with the red underline like Google does for all its app for the date of birth for example.

To see the error try to add a new account in any of the Google apps. It will ask you for the date of birth. Enter an invalid date and then press next.

Is there a way to do it without using the third party `MaterialSpinner` library?

[image: Screenshot of Google app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: The different pages you see when you create a new Google account on your device are simply a `WebView`. So they aren't using native components / widgets.

By default the `Spinner` Widget doesn't have a [setError(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError(java.lang.CharSequence)) method like the `EditText` (which is derived from the `TextView` by the way). So to show an error inside a Spinner you have to get the View of the currently selected item first and cast it as a TextView (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749971/creating-a-seterror-for-the-spinner)).
**Note:** ClassCastException will occur if you're using a layout of which the root element isn't a TextView.

Here's the catch of this approach: It won't look like the error message in your example or the error message of the `TextInputLayout`.
So in order to achieve the desired effect you have to use a third party library or implement it on your own.

**Further note:** If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner/blob/master/library/src/main/java/fr/ganfra/materialspinner/MaterialSpinner.java) of the [MaterialSpinner](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner) library you can see that it extends the `AppCompatSpinner` class and adds additional methods like the `setError` method you've mentioned. If you look at the [onDraw(...)](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner/blob/master/library/src/main/java/fr/ganfra/materialspinner/MaterialSpinner.java#L386) method you can see how the error is shown.