# I want to underline spinner (android)

Tags: android

I want to underline spinner like this one

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Help Here](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/android-material-themes-made-easy-with-appcompat)

```
style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
```

Comment: @EmenyBoudhri You can use theme and style as answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37113554

Comment: The resource `@style/Base_Widget_AppCompat_Spinner_Underlined` is marked as private in `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` which means that developers of appcompat library may easiliy change or even delete this resource, since it is not supposed to be used outside the appcompat library

Comment: How to do using programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

Just Add One View After Spinner like This...

```
  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />

   <View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
     android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your custom BaseAdapter and provide view which you want check this [custom-spinner-examples](http://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-spinner-examples.html)