# Prevent Spinner Underline become bold during click

Tags: android, android-spinner, underline

I need to add an underline below my Spinner. From these links:

- [Android Spinner Underline color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108954/android-spinner-underline-color)
- [I want to underline spinner (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229512/i-want-to-underline-spinner-android/43229600#43229600)

I have implemented the below:

In `reminder_dialog_fragment.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:theme="@style/MySpinnerTheme" />
```

In `styles.xml`

```
<style name="MySpinnerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- set color for underline below Spinner -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#ffcfd8dc</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#ffcfd8dc</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffcfd8dc</item>
</style>
```

I managed to display `underline` below Spinner & change the `underline's color`. But during `spinner onclick / highlighted`, there is some `animation effect` on Spinner:

1. `Ripple` effect on the `triangle` (right side of Spinner)
2. The `underline` below Spinner become `bold`

[image]

How can I remain the effect of (1), but disable the effect of (2)?

In other words, I want to prevent the `underline` become `bold` when Spinner is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try

```
 android:elevation="5dp"
```

in xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code snippet for removing Spinner Bottomline color

```
    app:ms_basecolor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:ms_hightlightcolor="@android:color/transparent"
```

I hope it will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

> There are multiple ways to do it. Try to give background as transparent.

```
<Spinner
  android:id="@+id/spTest"
  android:layout_margin="10dp"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:prompt="@string/spinner_prompt"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  android:entries="@array/spinnerList"/>
```

> Or create an EditText as shown in the code below:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_rectangale_border"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:hint="@string/spinner_prompt"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:padding="5dp" />
```

> You can find the drop_down_arrow from the vector asset. For the Border of EditText create a drawable named "edittext_rectangle_border.xml" and paste the below code in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#B9B9B9"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:topRightRadius="3dp"/>
</shape>
```

> After completing the above things, Open the java file and create a Dialog on EditText click by using onSetClickListner and display the list in the dialogbox. Later on selection of item set the EditText text.
>
> Hope you find it useful.