# How to Make my custom spinner like default spinner?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

So, i have a data which is from my table so i'm using adapter.  Here is how i set it up in my adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,false);
    // get your views here and set values to them

    TextView ItemCodetextview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemcode);
    TextView ItemNametextview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemname);

    GenerateItemdoModel current = dataModels.get(position);

    ItemCodetextview.setText(current.getItemCode());
    ItemNametextview.setText(current.getItemName());

    return row;
}
```

**list_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/itemcode"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/itemname"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="12sp"

        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**spinner in my xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Item Code"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/itemcodeval"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/valueitemcde"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**my default spinner (without adapter)**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tipe Rijek"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/tipeval"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40sp"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/valuetipe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> </LinearLayout>
```

here is the screenshot of custom spinner with adapter

[image]

and here is the default spinner

[image]

so, my question is how can i make my custom spinner looks like the default spinner ? thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Add top and bottom padding to `LinearLayout` parent in *list_item.xml* file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **list_item.xml** :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Add padding in **main layout** in item layout.

Answer (score 2):

Use this in you spinner

```
style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
```

Reference : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html

**(or)**

use this

Adding a small **attribute** as `android:spinnerMode="dialog"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108954/android-spinner-underline-color/37113554#37113554

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i will use @Vishva answer. Please tell me, where you find this reference ? `style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"`