# Android Spinner Underline color inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-styles

I am looking for a way to change all the spinners underline color, I made an edited version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37113554/2966583):

styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/MyCustomSpinner</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomSpinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined">
    <item name="android:minHeight">60dp</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:strokeColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

None of these work for me, so I noticed there is this comment on that answer:

> This won't work if the Spinner is inside a ScrollView. – IgorGanapolsky

And well... all my spinners are inside ScrollViews, so, how to change all the Spinners Underline color inside ScrollViews?

Answer (score 0):

Create new style like this and paste your color inside this style

```
<style 
name="Spinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner">
<item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
<item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/colorWhite</item>
<item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

After that set style to spinner like this

```
<Spinner
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="35dp"
  android:id="@+id/spinner"
  android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
  style="@style/Spinner"
/>
```

Comment: Do you know any way to do it for all spinners? (not for each one) the most of them are generated programatically.

Comment: Then add this spinner layout , in recycler  view layout or any view you use.