# How to create Dropdown with sub menus?

Tags: android, dropdown

[image]

How to create this type of dropdown in android ?
Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change spinner text size and text color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color)

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom spinner adapter with different itemTypes. Or you can change your spinner to some kind of ExpandableRecyclerView or ExpandableListView. If you need example links just let me know, but its pretty easy to find them in Google. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. i created custom popup window with expandable list inside. :)