# Change color of a disabled spinner Android

Tags: android, styles, spinner

When I **disable** my spinner it's dispalyed a text with an alpha so texte become a little not visible, my question how I can change this color ?
PS : I don't need to change the color of the spinner's texte.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change spinner text size and text color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color)

Comment: Not duplicate, I need to change the color of the state disabled of spinner not the color of the ensabled one

Comment: So you want to display it like a disabled one or it is not being displayed as a disabled one ?

Comment: not being displayed as a disabled one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a color folder in res and create a color state my_text_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/disableColor" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/enableColor"/>
</selector>
```

and your textview 
look like

```
  <TextView
    android:textColor="@color/my_text_color"
```

In adapter you need to inflate the layout that contain the Textview.
Inside your adapter constructor, send the id of textview also

```
public CustomAdapter(Activity context,int resouceId, int textviewId, List<RowItem> list){

        super(context,resouceId,textviewId, list);
        flater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    }
```

call it by

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.listitems_layout, R.id.title, rowItems);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/disabled_color"/>
    <item android:color="@color/normal_color"/>
</selector>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/customEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="Hello!"
    android:textColor="@drawable/edit_text_selector" />
```

// first code used in drawable/edit_text_selector.xml

Comment: Thank's for the replay, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Euphor08    Then, exactly what are you looking.