# To define own layout for the spinner's appearance

Tags: android, spinner

I tried to follow advices here:
[How to change spinner text size and text color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color#9476736)
and here:
http://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/changing-android-spinner-text-size

but without success.

First I tried to re-use/change the android.R.layout resources. I go to the definition by clicking in Android Studio the Ctrl + B key combination on android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item.xml.

I find the path to the resource file out there. I copied the resource file and added a new layout spinner_item.xml in my Package.R.layout folder ( which has this path: /home/myusername/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-25/data/res/layout) and change the textColor of textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android".
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

and then call it in adapter:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.blokkora);
        //Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.BlokkoraSorszama, android.R.layout.my_spinner);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
}
```

but I get 'Can not resolve symbol 'my_spinner' out there. Why?

Then I tried also to make my_spinner.xml in the project's explorer of this project and use it as adviced in the link above, but get again the above error message.

Finally I tried to add my_stiles.xml too and use it as adviced but still get the above mentioned error message. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/home/myusername/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-25/data/res/layout` is the *Android SDK* path.  You should not add your custom layouts here.

You should instead, add your custom layouts to your project path.

Something that looks like:

`path/to/your/project/src/main/res/layout/`

Resources like layouts and styles go into your projects **/res** folder.

Comment: If I do so as you adviced ( and I agree that that this is the right way to do it ) I still get the error message 'Can not resolve symbol 'my_spinner' out there. Why?

Comment: You reference layouts in your project's `/res` folder with `R.layout.my_spinner` not `android.R.layout.my_spinner`.