# change Spinner text color

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-spinner

I want to change the default text color in **Spinner** to any other color. But I have not find the solution yet. All I got a solution through **TextView** like 
[How to change spinner text size and text color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color)

Is there any other way, direct way for Spinner?

Note: Please provide solution for Xamarin. Thank you.

Comment: use a custom adapter. extend `ArrayAdapter` and override `getView` and `getDropDownView`

Comment: Whats wrong with this solution ? This is as simplest as it can be i guess .

Comment: @ADM Just curious to know, why they provide us this Spinner, which we can not customize, why? btw I am new to android.

Comment: Hold your curiosity and read the answers in the link . And all `AdapterView` are made for custom items so as Spinner too .

Comment: you can write custom style and add to spinner

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try like this only for selected item color change:

```
spinnerObject.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    ((TextView)parentView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
});
```

Another way:

```
<style name="spinnerTheme">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/gray_dark</item>
</style>

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:theme="@style/spinnerTheme"/>
```

Comment: help me with Xamarin, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, It works in pop up window text color but now the only problem left, is the default text color in spinner, which is black. how to change that?

Comment: write custom style to change the text color

Answer (score 2):

create a Sppinner code

```
<Spinner
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:entries="@array/planets"/>
```

You need to create your own layout file with a custom definition for the spinner item **spinner_item.xml**:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textColor="#ff0000" />
```

If you want to customize the dropdown list items, you will need to create a new layout file. **spinner_dropdown_item.xml**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:maxLines="1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:textColor="#aa66cc"/>
```

And finally another change in the declaration of the spinner:

```
 ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
 R.array.planets_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);  
 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: It might be working in (Java)Android, but I want to do in Xamarin. I have tried in both ways 1. placed under Resources/drawable/ with '.xml' extension and 2. under Resources/layout with '.axml' extension. I failed. Help me to understand it. Thank you.

Comment: im so sorry i dont check Your tag xamarin i dont know :( i want just help u but for java it will work as well

Answer (score 0):

Create a new XML layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:textColor="#962b2b"
android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

Now in the set the spinner adapter with the custom XML layout like this:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.custom_spinner,array);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: help me with Xamarin. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by adding below code to style.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="MySpinnerLook" 
    parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>    //any size
</style>
```

and in the xml where spinner is used add refrence to MyStyleLook using style tag like:

style="@style/MySpinnerLook"

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="@style/spinnerItemStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
android:padding="@dimen/padding_5"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_base" />




adapter?.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_text)

spSourceAccount.adapter = adapter
```